# How do I bypass marionette issues in Robot?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, firefox-marionette

I've been asked to evaluate Robotframework  and happy with what I've seen for the most part.  For it to be a viable option for me however, I need it to work in Firefox.

Marionette capabilities were a problem in my Ruby/Capybara environment, and I was able to shut it off.

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(marionette: false))
end
```

Getting the same thing in Robot / Python 2.7 / ff44.0 has generated an error in either direction.

When marionette is on:

```
${dc}   Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX  sys, selenium.webdriver
Set To Dictionary    ${dc}    marionette=${True}
Open Browser    ${url_bck_auto}     Firefox     desired_capabilities=${dc}
```

I get this:

> Our products rock                                   | FAIL |
>   WebDriverException: Message: Unsupported Marionette protocol version
>   2, required 3

If I turn it off, gecko bumps me to ff51.0.1(32-bit) and I get a different message:

> Our products rock                                   | FAIL |
>   WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox
>   version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. 
>   Profile Dir: c:\users\blah\appdata\local\temp\tmpqzlxha\webdriver-
>   py-profilecopy If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary 
>   constructor, check it for details.

Geckodriver is version 0.15.0

Any help will be appreciated,  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On `Windows 10` I'm running `Robot Framework 3.0`, `Selenium2Library 1.8.0`, `Selenium 3.0.2` and when I start your example, or the simplified single `open browser    http://google.com` I get the same result when using `Gecko 0.15.0`. The browser starts but does not move to the desired page. The driver closes successfully but the browser stays open.

When using the same setup, but downgrading `Geckodriver to 0.14.0` the results change, and the browser behaves as expected. Loads the page and closes when `Close Browser` keyword is called.

So, I recommend downgrading to `Geckodriver 0.14.0`.

Comment: On ```Windows 7```  I'm running ```Robot 3.0.2 S2L 1.8.0```  Trying Gecko 15 - 10 produced the same errors for me.